# Google app engine JUnit4 test is unable to find a default provider for creating the EntityManager

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, junit4, entitymanager

Trying to get work a JUnittest in a Google-App-Engine Eclipse-Environment

Unittest is testing a Class handling JPA Entities by getting an Entitymanager.

In the "Class under Test" following call succeds in productivety code, but fails if I run 
it as JUnit Test.

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
```

In JUnit Test above call throws an exception, "Unable to find a default provider" (see stack trace)

I moved the unittest directly in the src- Directory tree, for beeing sure that persistence.xml is reachable. It throws the same exception. It seems that the persistenceUnit with the name "transactions-optional" is reachable.

**How can I configure a default provider in JUnittest?**

I included following jars:
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar

The demo-Unittest on GAE- site is working fine:
[GAE Demo JUnittest](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting?hl=en)

**Do I have to do additional configuration in case of JPA-Use in the test-Setup?**

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
```

Console output with stack-trace:

```
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:17 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: Master/Slave
    Storage: In-memory

Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.client.GreetingService was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.persistence.EMF was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.connectivity.UserServlet was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.business.AShopperManagerTest was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.business.AShopperManager was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.shared.FieldVerifier was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.server.GreetingServiceImpl was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.client.AShopperCloud was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.client.GreetingServiceAsync was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM org.datanucleus.NucleusContext getValidationHandler
WARNING: Unable to create validator handler
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getValidationHandler(NucleusContext.java:1067)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.<init>(JPAEntityManager.java:138)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.newEntityManager(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:564)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:529)
    at ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.business.AShopperManager.register(AShopperManager.java:169)
    at ch.didge.ashopper.cloud.business.AShopperManagerTest.testRegister(AShopperManagerTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Jun 07, 2013 12:33:18 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: Master/Slave

    Storage: In-memory
```

Has anybody an idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for a default provider for BEAN VALIDATION, not JPA. If you want to use bean validation then put something like Apache BVAL or Hibernate Validator in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on meaning of putting Hibernate validator in classpath?...cause i have similar issue on appengine...thks